# Quality Gate New Blocker Issue and Blocker Issue with Over Leak Period checked

Tags: sonarqube

I want to confirm, if I create a Quality Gate with these 2 conditions:
1. New Blocker Issue
2. Blocker Issue (Over Leak Period is Yes)
Are they same condition?

Image

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I dont think so, probably "blocker issues" will be in meaning in the lifetime of the projects but new issues will be just from the last scan. 
Let me say scan 1 produce 2 blockers, 2nd scan produce 1 more blocker. Than the first case- blocker issues will be 3, but new one will be just one issue. Some more info can be found in docs https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have run a test with those two conditions, so I make the operator is greater than, and Error is 2.
Version 1 : I add 1 blocker issue, both of them is passed. I add another blocker issue, both of them is passed. Then I add another one blocker issue, both of them is failed.
I upgraded the version, so now I have version 2 with 0 blocker issue on leak period
Version 2: I add 2 blocker issue and both of them still passed, I try add another one blocker issue, and both of them is failed. 
That's why I think they are same condition.

Comment: Hm, ok, in this case I have no idea about it :) thanks for info